# How to format very small numbers in python?

Tags: python

How to format 1.3435434533e-8 into 1.34e-8 in python? Keep only two digits. The round() method will round this number to zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "g" formatting suffix on string mini-format language, used both by f-strings, and the `.format` method will do that:

```
In [1]: a = 1.34434325435e-8

In [2]: a
Out[2]: 1.34434325435e-08

In [4]: f"{a:.03g}"
Out[4]: '1.34e-08'

# in contrast with:
In [5]: f"{a:.03f}"
Out[5]: '0.000'
```

Comment: Thanks this works. One more question, is it possible to turn 1.34e-08 into 1.34e-8?

Comment: Not automatically. :-(  - it will require further manipulation of the string generated above. It can be done in a rather obscure expression nesting 2 f-strings. (I just learned this was possible yesterday): `f"{'e'.join(str(int(p)) if i else p for i,p in  enumerate(f'{a:.03g}'.split('e'))) }"`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like `round(number, 10)`, which leaves you with 10 digits after the decimal point. Since you shift the point by 8 (^-8), this leaves you with two printed decimal places.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this is very idiosyncratic since you need to know the exponent for every number that you want to format like that. I'm sure there's a better solution.

Comment: this won't work. "round" keeps the resulting number as a floating point, and modifies its value. Tghe usual best strategy as rounding comes around is to format what you are presenting: when the number is converted to a string.

Comment: I was assuming that this is formatting only. `print(round(a, 10))` works just fine. But I agree that your solution is a lot more elegant and I didn't know about the `g` suffix, so thanks for that!